# Running functional testing with it's own GUI

Tags: android, testing

I'm trying to test my android application, what i'm trying to do is to create GUI for the test application to show all the handled test and the results (instead of showing it in the JUnit tab on eclipse).
I've search over the net trying to find how to do it, didn't find anything related.
I have only one option in my mind on how to implement this:

create another package for testing in the original application and test the other packages, in this way I'll have my own GUI but it won't be in the unit testing platform.

Is there a better way to implement this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use something like: http://code.google.com/p/the-missing-android-xml-junit-test-runner/ instead of the standard test runner, any tests run will actually have junit xml stored on the phone. You can then create a simple app that will parse the xml into a nice easily read format after you have run tests.